# Signification de « non-endroit »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, néologismes, préfixes

Dans du texte d'opinion que l'on peut lire sur le forum de discussion informelle dédié au FSE, on trouve le terme suivant : « [non-endroit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62402542#62402542) ». J'ai une assez vague idée de ce qu'il pourrait signifier, mais aucune notion précise de son sens. Ce sens n'est pas reconnu dans les dictionnaires. Le TLFi fournit  un seul schéma que l'on puisse associer à ce terme.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/non-) **non-ville** .Sarcelles c'est l'archétype de la non-ville, le chef d'oeuvre de l'aberration  urbanistique (Paris-Match, 7 nov. 1970ds Gilb. 1971).

Les indications de section ne sont pas tellement informative pour ce cas-ci.

> B. − [Le mot constr. est un subst. de qualité; il est interprétable comme la nominalisation d'une relative négative: (x) qui n'est pas coupable → la non-culpabilité (de x)] V. non-activité, non-conformisme, non-conformité, non-contradiction, non-mitoyenneté, non-pesanteur, non-présence, non-valeur […]

Il est clair que l'entité désignée dans le texte *est* un endroit, comme d'ailleurs la non-ville est une ville. La réalité négative se situe donc au niveau d'une abstraction que l'on doit déduire du mot « endroit ». Je ne peux pas déterminer plus avant de quoi il s'agit. Est-ce une image qui par son exagération servirait à imprimer fortement dans l'esprit du lecteur la réalité d'un néant parfait quant à l'existence d'un certain état de chose ? Dans ce cas que serait cet état de choses ?

J'aurais peut-être posé cette question de façon très abrégée à l'auteur du texte en question, mais malheureusement, il ne peut plus être présent sur le FSE pendant plusieurs jours.

Quelqu'un aurait-il des explications supplémentaires en ce qui concerne ce terme, qui pourrait en fait n'être qu'un néologisme dû à l'auteur ([user Derniers Outrages](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/31569/derniers-outrages)).

Answer (score 5):

C'est une désignation péjorative ici qui refuse à des lieux, Montréal et la banlieue industrielle de Kuala Lumpur, la qualité d'être des « endroits ».

L'auteur de cette expression considère donc que Montréal n'a aucune des qualités requises pour être une ville digne de ce nom, ni même pour exister dans l'espace. C'est bien sûr un oxymore dont l'outrance ne peut être justifiée que par un désir de provocation, qui plus est ici en tant que commentaire à une nécrologie. C'est très exactement ce qu'on appelle sur Internet : « troller ».

Les « non-endroits » sont des « phénomènes dépourvus de matérialité » dans l'ouvrage suivant:

> *Le lieu précis (la baie de Naples, le lac Majeur, la forêt d’Ermenonville) handicape une lecture qui, à chaque paysage, ferait correspondre une unique identité. Le lien personnel qu’entretient le personnage avec son environnement fait du paysage un éventail de correspondances entre la nature et les émotions. Chaque élément de la composition est un choix, une élection gardée en mémoire, parce qu'il traduit un sens que le héros est le seul à détenir ou à savoir expliciter. Dans cette perspective, le lieu peut ressortir d’un **phénomène dépourvu de matérialité**, un **non-endroit**, une projective émotionnelle de paysage.*
>
> *Poèmes pour émouvoir, Anthologie de la poésie lyrique*, 2012.

On retrouve aussi des « non-endroits » dans un autre ouvrage :

> *Les premiers Mozambicains que nous apercevons sont dans une misère noire, le pays est dévasté. Les rares bâtiments que nous croisons sont des ruines zébrées de rafales de mitrailleuses. Quinze ans de guerre de libération suivis de quinze ans de guerre civile ont ramené toute la population rurale à l’âge de pierre. Les inondations chroniques ont jeté des centaines de milliers de gens sur des routes au bord desquelles ils ont fini par échouer en plantant sur le bas-côté des abris de fortune. C’est avec ces déshérités de la terre que nous vivons et marchons. Ils cabotent le long de l’artère, **de non-endroit en non-endroit**, pour vendre ou troquer de quoi manger : un oignon contre une poignée de massa, le maïs concassé local.*
>
> Alexandre Poussin, *Africa trek : 14000 kilomètres dans les pas de l'homme*, 2004.

Ici encore, « non-endroit » a un sens péjoratif. On le retrouve dans l'expression « **au milieu de nulle-part** », un autre oxymore.

Un « **non-endroit** », c'est donc un « **nulle-part** ». Étymologiquement, on peut le rapprocher du néologisme du XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle « **utopie** » dont les racines grecques sont *οὐ* (négation) et *τόπος* (topos: région, endroit), c'est à dire un endroit qui n'existe pas.

Comment: En somme, l'emploi sur le forum était de la rhétorique, une exagération qui visait à convaincre.

Comment: La provocation est à l'opposé du désir de convaincre.  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)

Comment: Je crois que c'est plutôt exagéré d'appeler cela du trolling; je n'y vois que de la rhétorique, un peu trop forte, certes, mais il semble que l'auteur a quelque chose à dire qui se veut sérieux. On ne peut pas s'en débarrasser avec la simple charge qu'il serait un petit délinquent. Après tout, ce n'est qu'une opinion et il ne ferait pas quelque chose de plus grave que de crier à la nullité d'une entité. Un Français sur le présent site a déclaré une fois que le Sacré Cœur était une église très laide ; c'était son opinion et personne n'a fait d'histoires.

Comment: Les goûts et les couleurs...